# How to construct a graphql mutation query request in php

Tags: php, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I am having the hardest time figuring out how to properly format a graphql api mutation POST request in php.

If I hard code the string and use it as the data in my POST request it works like this:
`'{"query":"mutation{addPlay(input: {title: \"two\"}){ properties { title } } }"}'`

But if I have a php array of the input values:

```
$test_data = array(
  'title' => 'two'
);
```

I can't seem to format it correctly. json_encode also puts double quotes around the keys which graphql is rejecting with the error `Syntax Error GraphQL request (1:26) Expected Name, found String`.

I ultimately need a solution that will convert a larger more complex array to something usable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reformatting the query allowed me to use JSON directly.

So my new query looks like this:

```
$test_data = array(
  'title' => 'two'
);

$request_data = array(
  'query' => 'mutation ($input: PlayInput) { addPlay(input: $input) { properties { title } }}',
  'variables' => array(
    'input' => $test_data,
  ),
);

$request_data_json = json_encode($request_data);
```

Then the `$request_data_json` is used in a POST http request.

Comment: Thanks @sagannotcarl for this I have been struggling for 2 days.